# camera.takePicture() not working on my JB & GB & Froyo phones

Tags: android, android-camera

Well, I updated my question again, totally this time.

I have tested the following code on Galaxy Nexus(JB), Moto-XX(GB), SAMSUNG(Froyo) one by one, with different problems/exceptions occurred.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
           public void onShutter() {
                  System.out.println("shutterCallback");
           }
          };

          PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
           public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                  System.out.println("onPictureTaken");
           }
          };

          PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
           public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                  System.out.println("jpegCallback");
                  FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                  try {
                  System.out.println("jpegCallback begin");
                     camera.startPreview();
                     File storagePath =  new File("/mnt/sdcard/");
                     File myImage = new File(storagePath, "example2.jpg");
                     outStream = new FileOutputStream(myImage); 
                     outStream.write(data);
                     outStream.close();
                    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                          System.out.println("jpegCallback FileNotFoundException");
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                          System.out.println("jpegCallback IOException");
                     e.printStackTrace();
                    } finally {
                     camera.stopPreview();
                     camera.release();
                    }
            }
          };

          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD) {
              for (int i = 0; i < Camera.getNumberOfCameras(); i++) {
              Camera.CameraInfo info = new Camera.CameraInfo();
              Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
              if (info.facing == Camera.CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_BACK) {
                     try{
                             Camera camera = Camera.open(i);
                             Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
                             camera.setParameters(parameters);
                              camera.startPreview();
                             camera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
                              System.out.println("takePicture ahead");
                             camera.takePicture(null, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
                              System.out.println("takePicture finish");
                            }
                            catch (Exception e){
                                  System.out.println("printStackTrace");
                                     e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                    }
                }
            }  
    }
```

### The detailed problems are:

---

**In Android4.1&4.2**, there are **three parts** of exceptions:
1.caused by "Camera camera = Camera.open(i);"

```
11-26 00:36:29.144: D/DOMX(132): ERROR: failed check:status >= 0 - returning error: 0x81000 - Can't connect
11-26 00:36:29.144: D/DOMX(132): ERROR: failed check:eRPCError == RPC_OMX_ErrorNone - returning error: 0x80001001 - Error initializing RPC
11-26 00:36:29.144: D/DOMX(132): ERROR: failed check:hRPCCtx != NULL - returning error: 0x81001 - NULL context handle supplied to RPC Deinit
11-26 00:36:29.144: D/DOMX(132): ERROR: rror in Initializing Proxy
11-26 00:36:29.144: E/CameraHAL(132): OMX_GetHandle() failed, error: 0x80001001
```

2.caused by "camera.startPreview();"

```
11-26 00:36:30.488: D/DOMX(132): ERROR: failed check:(eError == OMX_ErrorNone) || (eError == OMX_ErrorNoMore) - returning error: 0x80001005 - Error returned from OMX API in ducati
11-26 00:36:30.488: E/CameraHAL(132): Error while configuring rotation 0x80001005
```

3.caused by "camera.takePicture()"

```
11-26 00:36:30.495: E/CameraHAL(132): Adapter state switch INTIALIZED_STATE Invalid Op! event = 0x13
11-26 00:36:30.738: D/DOMX(132): ERROR: failed check:(eError == OMX_ErrorNone) || (eError == OMX_ErrorNoMore) - returning error: 0x80001005 - Error returned from OMX API in ducati
11-26 00:36:30.738: E/CameraHAL(132): Exiting function UseBuffersCapture because of ret 0 eError=80001005
```

So, the result is that **picture is not taken in Jelly Bean, even in common device like Galaxy Nexus i9250**.

---

Next, **in Android2.3**, there are **two parts** of exceptions:
1.caused by "Camera camera = Camera.open(i);"

```
E/CameraSettings(1235): Param type 53 not supported        
E/CameraSettings(1235): Param type 51 not supported        
E/CameraSettings(1235): Param type 50 not supported
```

2.Even though, the camera.takePicture() can still be executed. And the result shows picture is taken. Except for one problem: "E/MemoryHeapBase(1235): mmap(fd=50, size=0) failed (Invalid argument)"

```
11-26 01:28:33.835: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): prepareAsync_l
11-26 01:28:33.835: D/CameraHal(1235): Capture size 2048x1536, res enum 3
11-26 01:28:33.835: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): prepareAsync_l
11-26 01:28:33.835: D/CameraHal(1235): Setting capture format 0 header 2
11-26 01:28:33.835: I/HPAndroidHAL(1235): APILOG: SetCaptureDataFormat (1 2 0)
11-26 01:28:33.835: D/CameraHal(1235): Thumbnail enabled
11-26 01:28:33.843: E/MemoryHeapBase(1235): mmap(fd=50, size=0) failed (Invalid argument)
11-26 01:28:33.843: D/CameraHal(1235): Initializing capture memory raw: 0x42ee6000 (6295552), jpg: 0x434e7000 (3147776), pv 0xffffffff (0)
11-26 01:28:33.843: I/HPAndroidHAL(1235): APILOG: InitializeCaptureMemory(3 3147776 0x434e7000 6295552 0x42ee6000 0 0xffffffff)
11-26 01:28:33.843: I/HPAndroidHAL(1235): APILOG: InitializeCaptureMemoryBuffers(3 1 0_0x42de5d9c 6295552_0x42de5dc0 3147776_0x42de5d94 0_0x42de5dc8)
11-26 01:28:33.843: I/HPAndroidHAL(1235): APILOG: SetCaptureS2 with finish3A = 1
11-26 01:28:33.843: I/VorbisDecoder(1235): mNumChannels=1, mSampleRate=44100
11-26 01:28:33.843: E/OMXCodec(1235): Successfully allocated software codec 'VorbisDecoder'
11-26 01:28:33.843: I/VorbisDecoder(1235): mNumChannels=1, mSampleRate=44100
11-26 01:28:33.843: E/OMXCodec(1235): Successfully allocated software codec 'VorbisDecoder'
11-26 01:28:33.851: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): play_l
11-26 01:28:33.851: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): play_l
11-26 01:28:33.874: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): pause_l 1
11-26 01:28:33.874: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): reset_l
11-26 01:28:33.874: I/ExtendFileSource(1235): release pFilename = 0xfb690
11-26 01:28:33.874: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): reset_l
11-26 01:28:33.874: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): reset_l
11-26 01:28:33.882: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): pause_l 1
11-26 01:28:33.882: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): reset_l
11-26 01:28:33.882: I/ExtendFileSource(1235): release pFilename = 0xf9098
11-26 01:28:33.882: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): reset_l
11-26 01:28:33.882: I/AwesomePlayer(1235): reset_l
```

Hence, **in Android2.3, neither one of shutterCallback, rawCallback and jpegCallback would be called after the picture is taken**.

---

After that, **in Android2.2**, the shutterCallback and rawCallback is called after picture is taken. But neither of them can provide me data(byte stream). As introduced in [http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture(android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback, android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html#takePicture%28android.hardware.Camera.ShutterCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback,%20android.hardware.Camera.PictureCallback%29)
, the data will be null if there is no raw image callback buffer available or the raw image callback buffer is not large enough to hold the raw image. And I indeed **get null data in rawCallback**.

---

**Is all this staff caused by hardware incompatibility or the fault of codes?**
**Please help**

Comment: Do you get an exception ? If yes, post its log please.

Comment: Sorry. I have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully you've solved your problem by now, but I think the issue you are running into is that you are setting the camera preview to null, and it needs a valid `SurfaceView` as the preview to turn the flash on (at least on a Galaxy Nexus and some other Samsung devices...)

Culprit:

```
 camera.setPreviewDisplay(null);
```

Possible Solution:

Add a `SurfaceView` to your layout and specify it's size as 1px by 1px.  It seems that it has to be at least that big (size of 0 gives a different error).  It might work out to have the `SurfaceView` off screen (scrolled off or `RelativeLayout` or something)

Comment: This would cause an `IOException`

Comment: This answer is pretty old by now, but with Android, any hardware-interface type stuff really has to be tested on the hardware you'll be using (I know... that's about the least helpful advice I can give) and tested with new hardware and firmware releases... There are specs but the manufacturers really get to do whatever they want

Answer (score 1):

OK, this is in no was an answer, but I can't post comments, so I'll have a go at it in this form:
I can confirm the exceptions you are getting on my Galaxy Nexus.

In addition to that, but possibly helping a bit, I have to add a Thread.Sleep(500) between startPreview and takePicture if I want my pictures to be anything but black.

That said, I'm reading both cameras (in sequence as simultaneous attempts just don't work) and sometimes one camera works and the other generates the errors, sometimes both work and sometimes nothing works.

1. To solve issue with callback not being called: release the camera and try again. It usually works.
2. To solve issue with rotation 0x80001005: restart app / service
3. RPC_OMX issue: this seems really similar to what I experienced when I first bought this phone. It had 4.0.2 installed and occasionally, the camera would "get lost" - as if i weren't there. Only phone restart helps in such cases.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting an if statement that tests if the filepath your using is a real directory like this

```
if(file.isDirectory()){

    Log.w("file test---->","filepath is good");

}else{

    Log.w("file test---->","filepath is bad");

 }
```

Just saying "sdcard" usually is a bad idea as its different on multiple devices. Your better off creating your own directory to store your file in.

Comment: How did you test to see that onpicturetaken is never called?

Comment: I made it print by "System.out.println("jpegCallback")" in onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) .

Comment: where is the rest of your code where you are using your jpegCallback. I cant see where you call camera.takePicture()

Comment: I did put "camera.takePicture(null, rawCallback, jpegCallback)" in the last block, between "System.out.println("6")" and "System.out.println("7")".

Comment: Is that inside of a button click or something? forgive me if im asking simple questions but its possible you over looked something simple like that.....you never know lol.

Comment: Yes, I understand. But I actually didn't put them in a click event. Anyway, I'll have a try.

Comment: I tried and found a new exception ahead of the older ones: E/CameraHal(1235): Timed out waiting for capture to complete.

Comment: Hi, James. Thanks for helping. Did you use takePicture() before? I implement the similar code on Android2.3 and 4.1 phone, and got different problems.

Comment: Yes you have to use take picture in order to make the phone actually take a picture. Its possible that trying to implement some of those other parameters on certain devices may be causing your problems. Try taking the photo without implementing so many other parameters and see what happens.

Comment: Actually, I only use  Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters(); camera.setParameters(parameters); camera.startPreview(); to set the default parameter. Am I right assuming this?

Comment: unless you want to use specific camera features like the flash or other things related to image quality you can most likely do without the parameters. Try running it with no parameters. Ive built the camera before using no parameters and it works on all devices that way. I think your problem may be because your trying to use the front camera and that wouldnt take the same parameters.

Comment: The fact is I didn't set any specific parameter(front cam or back cam). I want to build camera app without preview. So I did not use SurfaceView/SurfaceHolder, and instead have "camera.setPreviewDisplay(null);". Do u think this is the problem? Have you tried taking picture without preview? Thanks

Comment: When I use Camera.setPreviewDisplay(SurfaceHolder), it works fine. I want to make some kind of spy camera to take picture stealthily when phone is lost or so. This is for my course project, not for bad purpose. I saw many such apps, but simply can't make it...

Comment: ahhhh yeah you need a preview. you can set up a surfaceview to use and then just dont assign it to any view in your layout.